# ElasticSearch 2, Logstash and Kibana : grok match can't create fields

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, grok

I try to parse a `message` field to generate differents fields. After research, the solution is to use `grok` with `match`. But in Kibana, I can't see the new fields (even after refresh or recreate fields from logstash indexes)

I try this in filter config :

```
grok {
  match => {
    "message" => "\[32m%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\[39m: memory: %{NOTSPACE:memory}, uptime \(seconds\): %{NUMBER:uptime}, load: %{NUMBER:load1},%{NUMBER:load5},%{NUMBER:load15}"
  }
}
mutate {
  rename => { "docker.id" => "container_id" }
  rename => { "docker.name" => "container_name" }
  rename => { "docker.image" => "docker_image" }
  rename => { "docker.hostname" => "docker_hostname" }
}
```

To transform this type of message :

```
[32minfo[39m: memory: 76Mb, uptime (seconds): 5529.927, load: 0.05322265625,0.1298828125,0.19384765625
```

To this variables :

- **load15**    0.19384765625
- **uptime**    5529.927
- **load1** 0.05322265625
- **load5** 0.1298828125
- **memory**    76Mb
- **loglevel**  info

I test the pattern in http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match and my matches work fine. But, In Kibana I can't retrieve this fields.

Thanks

Comment: New fields may not be visible in kibana.  Go to Settings -> Indices, select your index, and press the orange Reload/Refresh button.

Comment: i try this but it does not works

Comment: Make sure your fields are being created by logstash, by adding a stdout{} output stanza.

Comment: @throrin19 I had the same problem, the most likely reason is that the GROK pattern is not getting executed. Try to set an obvious condition from the incoming log so that it can match and trigger the GROK patterns.

Comment: did you find the answer?